# is it possible to delete docker images on a Nexus repository, via API, by creation date?

Tags: api, docker, rest, nexus, sonatype

I'm working with Sonatype Nexus 3.x.

I've a bunch of docker images that require a specific cleanup.

Cleanup policies provided by Nexus itself are not enough in my case, so I was wondering if is it possible to get a list of docker images sorted by date via REST api so that i can start processing my own pipelines

Answer (score 1):

It isn't as of 3.24.0.
You can see (watch/vote if you wish) the feature request here: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-17106